# Where do the Nightbloods come from in The 100?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-100

In The 100, where do all the [Nightbloods](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Grounders/Nightblood) come from? They fight to the death until there is only one alive and that one becomes the commander so where do new Night Bloods come from? And if they all die fighting each other, how do they have children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They come from the Nightblood serum created by Becca. She injected herself and became the first Nightblood and all concurrent Nightbloods are created by being injected with the same serum.

To quote the Wiki post:

> The serum created by Becca, which causes a person to become a Nightblood, is also referred to as Nightblood.

Also, Grounders don't fight to the death but can be carriers for the blood. To quote the Wiki post again:

> The majority of Grounders have normal colored blood, but may be carriers for the dark blood since Nightblood children can be born to non-Nightblood parents.

*Note: Never watched The 100. Please feel free to correct me in the comments*

Comment: She couldn't have injected a lot of people with night blood because it had to be made in space and when she came down she couldn't have been carrying a lot of it so it is unlikely that she gave a huge amount of people night blood.   As for the carriers idea although that is possible these people are also fighters so its a bit unlikely that the night blood carriers would stay around long, plus the carriers are never mentioned in the tv show, but can you maybe give me a link to where you found this info?

Comment: @Emptyisme It's in the link I edited into the question. However, the site did say that she brought a crate of serum with her.

Comment: Actually it was a case and they said that grounders could carry it implying not a lot of them probably did, but you answered my question good enough, but i still think they would all die out.

Comment: @Emptyisme judging from what I've read (very little) and seen (very little) I think you might be write that they would die out. But that wasn't your question :)

Comment: I know it wasn't my question, I was just wondering and I do recommend you watch it, it's a pretty decent series.

Comment: @Emptyisme I meant to when it was first aired in the UK but I missed the first episode and I never bothered to catch up.